# Playing sounds from an array of strings in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, string, url, audio

I'm trying to create an array of strings that can be used to initiate the urls for sounds to play. This works if I explicitly type in the file name as shown below, but how can I insert one of the array strings at a specific object index into the 'fileURLWithPath?

```
soundsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"test", @"test2",@"test3", nil];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
```

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array, so you should probably loop over the array, pulling out the next string on each iteration. You already know how to use `stringWithFormat:` to create a new string composed of other strings, as you're doing it with the resource path. Just do it again with the name of the file. (hint: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], nextFileName]`.)